# JQgrid / Entity Framework Issue with entities that have a relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, razor

I have an entity that has a relationship with another entity.  I am able to search on columns that are in the main entity, and include columns from the relationship entity.  But I need to be able to filter the list (search) on columns that are not in the relationship entity.

for example

the Invoice Entity contains a customerId property, and is related to the Customer Entity which contains the customerName property

I need to be able to search / filter the grid by customerName.

I am new to entity framework, please help.

thanks

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Your relation is 1->1. In these cases I usually return a custom class to the grid that has all the columns I need, including joins with other tables.

So basically what you need is to create a custom linq query with your resultset.

The mais query should follow this example:

```
var q = from i in ctx.Invoices
        join c in ctx.Customers on i.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
        select new{InvoiceID=i.InvoiceID, InvoiceDate=i.Date, CustomerName=c.Name};
```

Now, assuming we receive a CustomerName variable with the string to filter by c.Name we could do:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerName))
{
    q = q.where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(CustomerName.ToLower()));
}
```

Notice that I'm performing a ToLower() operation and a Contains, this will beahave as a LIKE ingnoring case sensitivity and searching for the string anywhere in the Customer Name.

At the end you'll return the q.ToList() serialized for the jqGrid...